# Why doesn't my DISTINCT ON expression work?

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct-on

**Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (geom_line),gid 
FROM edge_table;
```

I have a edge table which contains duplicates and I want to remove duplicate edges keeping one of them, but the syntax itself is wrong?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ON (geom_line) geom_line, gid FROM edge_table;` Read: http://www.postgresqlforbeginners.com/2010/11/sql-distinct-distinct-on-and-all.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma is the problem.

If you want `geom_line` included in the result, use

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (geom_line) geom_line, gid FROM edge_table;
```

Else use

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (geom_line) gid FROM edge_table;
```

But if your objective is just to remove duplicates, I'd say that you should use

```
SELECT DISTINCT geom_line, gid FROM edge_table;
```

`DISTINCT` guarantees uniqueness over the whole result set, while `DISTINCT ON` guarantees uniqueness over the expression in parentheses. If there are several rows where the expression in parentheses is identical, one of these rows is picked. If you have an `ORDER BY` clause, the first row will be picked.

`DISTINCT a, b` is the same as `DISTINCT ON (a, b) a, b`.

Comment: what's the basic difference between distinct on and distinct alone?

Comment: I have extended the answer to explain that.